# Why createToken() of Stripe for android sometimes don't create the token?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

The code below shows an AlertDialog that collects the credit card data, namely number, validity and CVC for payment with Stripe. With this data, the stripe.createToken function (...) should either return a token to TokenCallback (). The problem is that even with correct card data about one in five, the token is not fetched and no error is returned.

```
private void dialogRenewWithStripe() {

    final ViewGroup nullParent = null;
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_container_renew_stripe, nullParent, false);

    ...

    CardMultilineWidget mCardMultilineWidget = view.findViewById(R.id.add_source_card_entry_widget);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = dialogBuilder2(mContext);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_pay);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.msg0333));
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialogInterface, i) -> { });
    builder.setPositiveButton("CONFIRM", (dialogInterface, i) -> { });

    alertDialog2 = builder.create();
    alertDialog2.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
        ((AlertDialog)dialogInterface).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            btnRenew.setImageAlpha(255);
            btnRenew.setEnabled(true);
            alertDialog2.dismiss();
        });
        ((AlertDialog)dialogInterface).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (mCardMultilineWidget.getCard() != null) {

                alertDialog2.dismiss();
                dialogWhait( getResources().getString(R.string.msg0251) );

                Stripe stripe = new Stripe(mContext, "pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                stripe.createToken(
                        mCardMultilineWidget.getCard(),
                        new TokenCallback() {

                            public void onSuccess(Token token) {

                                alertDialogWhaiting.dismiss();
                                dialogWhait( getResources().getString(R.string.msg0330) );

                                String stringData = "{" +
                                        "\"_ind\":\"" + Long.toString(paymentOption._option_id) + "\"," +
                                        "\"_token\":\"" + token.getId() + "\"}";

                                ServerTask serverTask = new ServerTask(AccountActivity.this, API_CKECK_OUT_STRIPE, stringData);
                                serverTask.execute();

                            }

                            public void onError(Exception error) {

                                alertDialogWhaiting.dismiss();

                                dialogError(
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.msg0331),
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.msg0332)+" "+error.getLocalizedMessage()
                                );
                                btnRenew.setImageAlpha(255);
                                btnRenew.setEnabled(true);
                            }

                        }
                );

            }
            else {
                toast...
            }

        });
    });
    alertDialog2.show();

}

private static class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String data;
    private String urlString;

    private WeakReference<AccountActivity> activityReference;

    private ServerTask(AccountActivity context, String urlString, String data) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        this.urlString  = urlString;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String serverResponse = "";
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlString); //there is a connection between the code and PHP script. This is tested.
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String urlParameters = URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            dStream.flush();
            dStream.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            serverResponse = responseOutput.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return serverResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String serverResponse) {
        super.onPostExecute(serverResponse);

        AccountActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;

        PaymentResponse paymentResponse = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(serverResponse, PaymentResponse.class);

        activity.alertDialogWhaiting.dismiss();

        activity.btnRenew.setImageAlpha(255);
        activity.btnRenew.setEnabled(true);

        if (!paymentResponse._t_error.equals("")) {
            switch (paymentResponse._t_error) {
                case "400":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "401": 
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "402":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "404":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "409":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "429":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                case "500":
                case "502":
                case "503":
                case "504":
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
                default:
                    activity.dialogError( "TITLE", "message");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            activity.dialogRenovatio(paymentResponse);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and can't find the answer anywhere. Did you have any hint from Stripe team ? Can it be linked to the fact that it is a test key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/803#issuecomment-461840143

I moved the inline anonymous TokenCallback class in StripePaymentDialog#createStripeToken to be an instance variable (see below) and the issue seems to go away. I believe that the anonymous class is being garbage collected when it's inline.

```
public class StripePaymentDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull private final TokenCallback mTokenCallback = new TokenCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
            Log.d("Stripe Token Success: ", token.toString());
            setSubmitSuccess(token.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            if (error != null && error.getMessage().length() > 0) {
                Log.d("Stripe Token Error: ", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                setErrorMessage(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                setSubmitError();
            }
        }
    };

    private void createStripeToken() {
        mStripe.createToken(mCard, mDefaultPublishKey, mTokenCallback);
    }
}
```